# ValidateWithoutUpdate doesn't ever execute configured ValidationRules?

Tags: wpf, validation, binding, idataerrorinfo, validationrule

I'm trying to understand why calls to [BindingExpression.ValidateWithoutUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase.validatewithoutupdate.aspx) doesn't actually do what it advertises.

I've got some cranky validation (I've removed the boring details from my sample code; suffice it to say it has to do with WF4 ModelItem limitations) that I have to add to a binding via an attached property (e.g., from code and not in xaml).

```
    // d is DependencyObject and prop is DependencyProperty
    var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(d, prop);
    binding.ValidationRules.Add(new MyDerpyValidatonRule());
```

Nothing crazy here.  But the problem is that **validation isn't run the first time the control is shown, so validation errors are not exhibited in the UI.**

```
<TextBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    x:Name="derp"
    Text="{Binding Derp, NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
    t:MyDerpyValidator.TargetProperty="{x:Static TextBox.TextProperty}" />
```

Binding looks good, works after the value is changed, but when first shown, I get a frownyface instead of the expected red Border:

[image]

Initially, I tried calling ValidateWithoutUpdate *after I added the ValidationRule to the Binding.*  This didn't seem to work.  Later, I used the Dispatcher to try and put this call off until the application was all warm and cozy (maybe it didn't validate because the tea hadn't finished brewing yet, hell I dunno)

```
var exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, prop);
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (Action<BindingExpression>)(x =>
    {
        x.ValidateWithoutUpdate();
    }),
    DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
    exp);
```

I'm pretty sure this worked once.  **Once**.  Never worked again.  Might have been an incorrect observation on my part.

Later, I tried all kinds of things to get **ValidateWithoutUpdate** to actually ***do something***.  I even tried calling it from within an event handler that would happen way down the road

```
public DerpyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    derp.MouseEnter += DERPDAMNYOU;
}

void DERPDAMNYOU(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    derp.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).ValidateWithoutUpdate();
}
```

*It never friggen works.*

#### What do I need to do to get BindingExpression.ValidateWithoutUpdate() to friggen validate?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's some weird behaviour. Looking at some of the validation code with ILSpy it has some checks in the background that determine if validation is required or not, and I was too scared to follow it all the way through, so, I too, just tried some random stuff.

This is the first thing I tried that worked:

In your attached property changed handler, after

```
binding.ValidationRules.Add(new MyDerpyValidatonRule());
```

add

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(d, prop);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(d, prop, binding);
```

This must somehow set the internal 'validation requred' flag which forces it to validate.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try this out tomorrow.

Comment: It worked.  Once.  Now it isn't working anymore.  I need to investigate this further.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that was because the value I was validating was the BindingExpression.  Need to tweak the ValidationStep.

Comment: Okay, going with ConvertedProposedValue it works.  Reliably.  I wish there was a more direct solution; I kind of consider this a hack.  But without reflection I don't see any other alternative right now, and I don't observe any side effects (as of yet) of this method.  Accepted!  Thanks, and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my project was:

```
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(textbox, TextBox.TextProperty);

        binding.UpdateSource();
        binding.ValidateWithoutUpdate();
```